# How to use TLS session tickets in Android to mimimize Firebase Realtime Database download bandwidth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The Firebase Realtime database documentation states that one should issue TLS session tickets to reduce download bandwidth. How to do that?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing, apparently, my app is making frequent and short connection, even if I remove all the RTDB related codes, only the realtime database SDK was included. Have you got the answer, Haneesh Bhardwaj?